# Scolling list with jQuery

Tags: jquery, list, scroll

My javascript is not up to scratch at the moment and I am stumped with this!

I need to create an animated list with javascript like this one - http://www.fiveminuteargument.com/blog/scrolling-list.

What I want is to take a list like so

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li> 
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
</ul>
```

And display two at once, then display them in a loop, 2 at a time.

Even pseudo code would help to get me started.

Comment: What's wrong with the information provided by the link you gave?

Comment: There is a step missing - it doesn't explain how to go from list as above to the effect it describes. My javascript is not good enough to get how to add/remove elements.

Comment: Hi Chris. I'm the author of that tutorial. It was my aim to pretty much spell out each and every step, so I'm sorry if there's anything missing. The code is available to download at the very of the article, and I'd suggest that's the best place for you to start. If you have any specific questions, I'd be happy to answer them - ideally via the email address sitting behind the 'contact' link on my site.

Comment: Thanks Bobby - I did go through it but just wasn't sure of how to go from list to result. Probably didn't read it thoroughly enough. Anyway client changed mind so effort was in vain!

Answer (score 3):

With the html you included in your message, you can run the following.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //hide all the list items
    $("ul li").hide();
    //call the function initially
    show_list_item();
});

function show_list_item(){
    //fade in the first hidden item. When done, run the following function
    $("ul li:hidden").first().fadeIn("slow", function(){
       //if there are no more hidden list items (all were shown), hide them all
       if($("ul li:hidden").length == 0){
          $("ul li").hide();
       }
       //call this function again - this will run in a continuous loop
       show_list_item();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks yuval - I get $("ul li:hidden") is not a function error when this runs. I'm using 1.3.2 though, so not sure why.

Comment: did you include jQuery? That's the first thing that comes to mind when you get a not-a-function with the dollar sign. Do you have any other JS libraries included? Try testing this in a page with only jquery included, this code, and the html included. It should work without a problem with 1.3.2. Also make sure you wrap your js with `<script type="text/javascript">...</script>` or include it in a separate file. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Hmmm, same error - I put the plain html file up here: http://jonesonter.notomato.com.au/wp-content/themes/jonesonter/test.html.

Comment: The proper selector is `$('ul li:hidden :first')` not `$('ul li:hidden').first()`

Comment: Now I get a warning - unknown class or pseudo class element :hidden.

Comment: `$('ul li:hidden :first')` has an extra space. It should be `$('ul li:hidden:first')`.

Comment: Nearly there - if you look at the original link you'll see that they scroll up so only 2 items are visible at any one time. I am starting to see how it could be done though. I think I need to rotate them in a loop and then make a container that has hidden overflow to limit the view to 2 at a time.

Comment: Right! What would make more sense is to just fade in 2, hide them, fade in the next two, hide them etcetc in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just a modification to Yuval's code, to get the 'two at a time' behaviour working:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //hide all the list items
    $("ul li").hide();
    //call the function initially
    show_list_item();
});

function show_list_item(){
    //fade in the first hidden item. When done, run the following function
    $("ul li:hidden:first").fadeIn("slow", function(){
       //if there are no more hidden list items (all were shown), hide them all
       if($("ul li:hidden").length == 0){
      $("ul li").hide();
       }
    });
    $("ul li:hidden:first").fadeIn("slow", function(){
       //if there are no more hidden list items (all were shown), hide them all
       if($("ul li:hidden").length == 0){
      $("ul li").hide();
       }
       //call this function again - this will run in a continuous loop
       show_list_item();
    });
}
```